# Blazor WebAssembly slow at compile (up to 30 secs)

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

My Blazor WebAssembly project is became slow at compile. It takes about 25-30 seconds to compile even with a tiny modification in one of my razor components.

I already tried to set `BlazorWebassemblyEnableLinking` to false in my all 3 .csproj files without any effect.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <BlazorWebassemblyEnableLinking>false</BlazorWebassemblyEnableLinking>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This was suggested here https://remibou.github.io/Make-your-Blazor-development-faster/

Tested scenario:

- Adding `BlazorWebassemblyEnableLinking` in my 3 .csproj files (xxx.Client, xxx.Server, xxx.Shared)
- Modifying a simple text in one of my .razor component
- Save & compile (CTRL+S & CTRL+SHIFT+B)
- ==> It takes 25-30 seconds to finish

I know this is preview of Blazor Wasm but it was a pain to code in this situation.

Any advices for speeding up the coding process ?

I found a trick to speed up compilation time. Simply create a new folder (let's say Pages excluded) right click, `Exclude from project`. Then I moved a maximum of razor components inside of it. If I am currently busy working on a specific part of my Blazor application, I moved all files except that part to the excluded folder. In my case compilation time goes from 30 secs to 5 secs. When needed (before releasing for publishing something) I simply have to move back excluded files to original Page folder. This trick suits my needs for now until compilation times will be better (I hope in a near future).

Comment: You could/should post that Update part as a self-answer.

Comment: How long does a `dotnet new blazorwasm` project take to compile?

Comment: Another technique is to move any Razor components you can into a library so they don’t have to be recompiled each time

Comment: @MisterMagoo for a new project it takes only a few seconds. So it seems the more Blazor components I have in my project, the more time it takes to compile. At this moment, I must have more than 20 components.

Comment: I think this project was originally written on an older Blazor preview - am I right? If so, make sure your csproj files don't have any of the old properties that were needed - compare to a brand new project file.

Comment: @MisterMagoo this is not the case. Don't have any old properties. You can still take a look at my github link for my sources. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I found a trick to speed up compilation time. Simply create a new folder (let's say Pages excluded) right click, Exclude from project. Then I moved a maximum of razor components inside of it. If I am currently busy working on a specific part of my Blazor application, I moved all files except that part to the excluded folder. In my case compilation time goes from 30 secs to 5 secs. When needed (before releasing for publishing something) I simply have to move back excluded files to original Page folder. This trick suits my needs for now until compilation times will be better (I hope in a near future).

[image]